# Can't merge data from file to database (MySql)

Tags: mysql, database, macos, merge

my problem is I can't put data from one file(web.sql) to the database I created(web) in MySql. I put web.sql in bin folder and type this in terminal(I'm using Mac):

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql –uroot –p web < web.sql; /usr/local/mysql/bin/web.sql
```

and I get that error: `ERROR 1064 (42000)`

How do I put the content I need from web.sql to web?

Comment: Is there any more to the error message?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql –uroot –p web < web.sql' at line 1

Comment: Are you typing that into the `mysql>` prompt? It's supposed to be a Terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should type that command at the Terminal's shell prompt:

```
$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql –uroot –p web < web.sql
```

not at the `mysql` prompt:

```
mysql> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql –uroot –p web < web.sql; /usr/local/mysql/bin/web.sql
```

Comment: now I get this: -bash: web.sql: No such file or directory -bash: /usr/local/mysql/bin/web.sql: cannot execute binary file

Comment: This command assumes that `web.sql` is in your current directory. You should either use `cd` to change to the folder where you saved the file, or use the full path of the file. There's no way for me to know where you put it.

Comment: Here's what I put in Terminal: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql –u root –p web < /usr/local/mysql/bin/web.sql and it seemed to work out, there was a lot of text and now when I launch MySql and try to see some tables it says Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: that's what I typed in: mysql> use web;
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Hmm, okay, thanks anyways! One more thing: I try to connect to MySql using php and when I wanna see the result of SELECT * FROM the table of web.sql in browser it shows: "Table 'web.web' doesn't exist". What is wrong?

Comment: What is the name of the table? When you write `web.web`, you're trying to access a table named `web` in the database named `web`.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are missing a space between -u and "root". It's interpreting "-uroot" as 1 command, which is does not recognize.

Comment: When an option requires a parameter, the space is optional.

Comment: I don't think it deserves a downvote though @Barmar. The guy is new, chill.

Comment: @hansmei The answer is simply wrong. Downvoting isn't intended as an insult, just a way of stating that an answer is not helpful.